# Android 10+ android.permission.NETWORK_STACK for hidden api

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am testing a new app on a physical device:

- REDMI NOTE 9 PRO
- android 10
- MIUI 12

I am trying to access to **startSoftAp** that is a hidden method of **WifiManager** class. That is I want programmatically start and stop tethering.

Following this approach and many other links such as:

- https://www.xda-developers.com/android-development-bypass-hidden-api-restrictions/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/deyz14/apparently_you_can_destroy_hidden_api_blacklist/

I am facing a new issue regarding

> android.permission.NETWORK_STACK

that I am not able to fix. The main cause is

> Caused by: **java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user
> 10448 nor current process has android.permission.NETWORK_STACK.

Obviously I tried to specify this via manifest file but this is a non-SDK permission or hidden permission. Then them method described by many programmer to bypass hidden API seems is missing something about this permission.

Here is the stack trace.

```
**java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.example.tel_info.MainActivity.setHotspot(MainActivity.java:111)
  at com.example.tel_info.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5372)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5280)
  at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.example.tel_info.HideClass.startSoftApInstance(HideClass.java:42)
Caused by: **java.lang.SecurityException: WifiService: Neither user 10448 nor current process has android.permission.NETWORK_STACK.**
  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2074)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2042)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1990)
  at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub$Proxy.startSoftAp(IWifiManager.java:3031)
  at android.net.wifi.WifiManager.startSoftAp(WifiManager.java:2721)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
  at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1906)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1934)
  at com.android.server.wifi.WifiServiceImpl.enforceNetworkStackPermission(WifiServiceImpl.java:915)
  at com.android.server.wifi.WifiServiceImpl.startSoftAp(WifiServiceImpl.java:1206)
  at android.net.wifi.IWifiManager$Stub.onTransact(IWifiManager.java:1359)
```

**How to grant this to my app? Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did you found a solution for this problem? I'm currently facing the same issue with Ethernet Manager. Seems like the signature is only allowed when the app has the same signature as the system: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml